# On window resize removeAttr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed menu sticked to the top. When I scroll down the page starting at 1px from the top, my fixed menu will change style. But as I'm making the website responsive and I resize my window the recently added style doesn't dissapear (after first scrolling down and back up).

Hope this is a little bit clear.

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){       
    var scroll_pos = 0;

    var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();

    if (windowWidth > 768) {

        jQuery(document).scroll(function() { 

            scroll_pos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 1) {
                jQuery("nav").css('background-color', 'black');
                jQuery("nav").css('padding', '10px 0px');
                jQuery("nav").css('transition', '0.3s ease-in-out all');
            } else {
                jQuery("nav").css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)');
                jQuery("nav").css('padding', '20px 0px');
                jQuery("nav").css('transition', '0.3s ease-in-out all');
            }
        });
    } else {
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        jQuery("nav").removeAttr("style");
    });
    }
});
```

The structure of my HTML is like this:

```
<div class="toggle">
    <img src="images/menu.png">
</div>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for some help

Comment: A side question: What is the html `<nav>`? is it a valid html 5 tag?

Comment: put the the function inside `$(window).resize(function() {});` and it will work, because what `ready` does is it check the size of the window when the page load not when u resize it.

Comment: @reporter: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) says it was introduced in html5. Or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) if you prefer a 'more spohisticated' example

Comment: @ctf0: I tried, but it is still the same (I'll update so you can see what I did). Thanks tho.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans: In regard to your question, should this not be a media query (i.e. within your css?)

Comment: @JeroenBellemans ,the new code still wont work because the `else` is still inside the `ready` , `Balázs Varga` answer is what u need.

Comment: I tested your code  by using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/hcwd035m/ and I might have got it working. For testing purposes I changed:      (windowWidth > 200) , and added some text + made the scrollbar visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new javascript function like:

```
function resize() {

    var scroll_pos = 0;
    var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery(document).scroll(function() { 
        if (windowWidth > 768) {
            scroll_pos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 1) {
                jQuery("nav").css('background-color', 'black');
                jQuery("nav").css('padding', '10px 0px');
                jQuery("nav").css('transition', '0.3s ease-in-out all');
            } else {
                jQuery("nav").css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)');
                jQuery("nav").css('padding', '20px 0px');
                jQuery("nav").css('transition', '0.3s ease-in-out all');
            }
        } else {
            jQuery("nav").removeAttr("style"); 
        }
    });
}
```

then you can easily call it when the screen was resized.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resize();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    resize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this works for me :) +1 EDITED[if i only had 15 reputation] :D

Comment: I've encountered another problem now. As i resize the window the problem is solved. BUT each time I scroll down and up, the transparant background returns, until i resize the window again. Suggestions?

Comment: Flip the approach of the jQuery(document).scroll line, and the if above it! Check the width INSIDE the scroll event, because now the scroll event was attached to jQ and played each step because you loaded the page with larger than 768 width. If you load it in smaller resolution, this part of code will stop working completely. You must not define events inside if's just in some custom cases (not like this).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use css directly?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    // CSS style for +768 px
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    // CSS style for less 768px
}
```

Comment: It wohn't work, because the `#`refrences to an html object with id `nav` and not to a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using css classes and media queries. And rather than adding each css style with jquery then you can change the class.

css styles:

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .top{
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            padding: 20px 0px;
            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
        }

        .scrolled{
            background-color: black;
            padding: 10px 0px;
            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        //Style when windows is less than 768px
    }
```

javscript scroll function becomes:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    scroll_pos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll_pos > 1) {
        $("nav").removeClass('top');
        $("nav").addClass('scrolled');
    } else {      
        $("nav").removeClass('scrolled');
        $("nav").addClass('top');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my methodology isn't what is should be, thanks for reply, I'll try it out! :)